# Hello there, how to check which lists in a class have expired time element in them?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

In a class I have lists, in those lists I have maps, each map has 'interval' and 'time' element, I want to check which of those 'time' elements have expired and then pass those lists to further sorting according to interval (this sorting thing is working already), just not sure how to check which lists have expired 'time' in them?

In the code I have marked with //TODO part that is missing

Thank you

```
class QuizBrain {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> products = [
    {
      'id': 24,
      'interval': 10000,
      'time': '2021-12-14 20:37:21.190473',
    },
    {
      'id': 36,
      'interval': 20000,
      'time': '2020-11-14 20:37:21.190453',
    },
    {
      'id': 48,
      'interval': 30000,
      'time': '2020-12-14 20:37:21.190453',
    },
  ];

  min() {
    //TODO need to set condition to check which lists 'time' is expired, then i pass those that 'time is expired to further sorting beneath

    if (products != null && products.isNotEmpty) {
      products.sort((a, b) => a['interval'].compareTo(b['interval']));
      //print(products);
      return (products.first['id']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert the `time` attributes into `DateTime` objects and compare them to now using `compareTo`:

```dart
final now = DateTime.now();
final expired = products.where((item) {
  final itemTime = DateTime.parse(item["time"]);
  return itemTime.compareTo(now) < 0;
});
```

Then if I've read your question correctly you just need to replace `products` with `expired` in your if statement.

This is from the docs of `compareTo()`:

`this.compareTo(other)`

Compares this DateTime object to [other], returning zero if the values are equal.

Returns a negative value if this DateTime [isBefore] [other].
It returns 0 if it [isAtSameMomentAs] [other], and returns a positive value otherwise (when this [isAfter] [other]).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this looks very promising, though orElse: produces an error:
The named parameter 'orElse' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [midi_app] lib/trainer.dart:38)

Comment: Ah sorry about that! It's my mistake I've updated the answer, there shouldn't be an `orElse`. It's only for `firstWhere` rather than where. I'm used to `firstWhere` in the code I write so typed it by default, sorry!

Comment: Thank you for fast response, was working before, will check it, tried actually already without orElse, and it was working, but I still have some issues with implementing it all, so wasn't sure if it was working properly, checked also, syntax was correct, so yeah this was not needed.

Working now on it and if I get it working will accept your answer, thank you again